# Plain Old PHP object to json conversion

Tags: php, json

I am developing a web application in php. I want to convert a array of plain old php object to its json equivalent. Is there any solution for that? Please help me to find the answer... thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **[json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)**

Example:

```
$arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Output:

```
{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}
```

To do the opposite, you can use json_decode()

Answer (score 0):

[json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) is the best option that you can do here. it Returns the JSON representation of a value.

```
$arr = array('1'=>'ssd','sdsd'=>'ssdd');
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Please have a look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.json.php) for the json php functions.